# find copy paste increment loop vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Search starting at a specific cell on X WS, copy cell and paste to specific cell on Y 'WS ', find that value, move 6 cells right and copy cell, then go back to X WS, increment '1 'row and repeat until value "STOP_4" is reached.
I can do this manually and it works but not having success with loop and especially incrementing next row
I think I got it?

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Loop100()  'test on smaller ws


    ' Define variables
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsX As Worksheet: Set wsX = wb.Sheets("X")
    Dim wsY As Worksheet: Set wsY = wb.Sheets("Y")
    Dim rngX As Range
    Dim rngY As Range
    Dim strStart As String: strStart = "START"
        
    Set rngX = wsX.Cells.Find(strStart) ' Find the "start" cell in wsX
       
    Do While Not rngX Is Nothing   ' Loop until stops, strange negative logic
        
        
        If rngX.Offset(1, 0).Value = "STOP_4" Then Exit Do ' Loop until "STOP_4"

        rngX.Offset(1, 0).Copy 'incremnt row

        wsY.Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'paste to wsY
        
        Set rngY = wsY.Range("A2:E100").Find(wsY.Range("B1").Value) 'find wsY "B1"
        
        If Not rngY Is Nothing Then ' Neg logic wierd
            rngY.Offset(0, 6).Copy  'copy wsY Data
            rngX.Offset(1, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'paste wsY data to wsX
        End If
        
        
        Set rngX = rngX.Offset(1, 0) ' back to wsX next row
    
    Loop

End Sub
```

[image: before after X]

[image]

Comment: Your description is lacking in clarity. Is this correct: You have a range of values in worksheet X, you want to iterate cell by cell in this range until you hit `4STOP` value. For each cell you want to go to Worksheet Y (not clear what sheet/range though), search for that cell's value and then put <something> in the cell 6 cells from the right of the found cell. Is that right? What is it that you are wanting to put in that cell that is 6 cells to the right? What is the range that you are searching in Worksheet Y?

Comment: I have two different workbooks X and Y , I want to increment row by row through that workbook (X), I have column (a) that has a in (X) cell called “start” then increment one row. The value in that row will be copied to the Y workbook, cell B1, then find that value. Then move 6 cells right and copy that value. Goto WB X , paste that value in cell B1. Loop back to WB X. increment down one row repeat. Been working on this for several days.  I showed 1 iteration I’ve been  trying to get it to loop, even if it gets stuck in a continuous loop that would be progress then I could do a do while decisio

Comment: `wsX.Range("A13").Value` = "start" or is it = "99900694235" because you're doing both and it's uncertain what you want from it. Then you copy from `wsY.Range("N1622")` (I assume you found the value there?) and copy it to `wsX.Range("F45")` which is not B1 at all like you just mentioned. Afterwards you copy another time from wsY, this time `wsY.Range("P1622")` which is not 6 columns to the right from K or N and then paste it to `wsX.Range("D45")` which makes even less sense.

Comment: wsX.Range("A12").Value = "start", then increment one row, copy "99900694235"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) There is no need copying everything to the clipboard first if you just want to do `Dest.Value = Orig.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

This following sub will

- loop through the A-column values of sheet "First" (Set in the variable wsX)
- look for them in sheet "Second" (Set in the variable wsY)
- place the searched for Value in Y-sheet's B1 (still unsure why)
- take the value 6-columns further of the found cell to the row you were on in wsX (in E-column).

I also used a single workbook for ease of use on my end, you'll have to adjust where needed on that front.

arrXA is a Variant array, they're mostly used to speed up things as this works in memory rather than having to consult the sheet itself like `wsX.Cells(i,1).Value`

```
Sub beerFound()
    Dim wsX As Worksheet, wsY As Worksheet
    Dim lRowX As Long, sRng As Range, i As Long, startRng As Range
    
    Set wsX = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("First") 'change this to your needs
    Set wsY = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Second")
    
    lRowX = wsX.Range("A" & wsX.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set startRng = wsX.Range("A1:A" & lRowX).Find("START", wsX.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt:=xlPart).Offset(1)
    Dim arrXA, fRng As Range, lRowY As Long, lColY As Long
    arrXA = wsX.Range("A" & startRng.Row & ":A" & lRowX).Value 'all the search values to loop through
    lRowY = wsY.Range("A" & wsY.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'assuming the A-column is always filled
    'lColY = wsY.Cells(1, wsY.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'assuming the first row is filled but pointless now you verified it's A:E
    Set sRng = wsY.Range("A1:E1").Resize(lRowY)
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrXA, 1)
        If UCase(arrXA(i, 1)) = "4STOP" Then Exit For 'done with the list
        Set fRng = sRng.Find(arrXA(i, 1), sRng.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt:=xlPart)
        If Not fRng Is Nothing Then 'if something is found
            wsY.Cells(1, 2).Value = arrXA(i, 1) 'B1 gets the value
            startRng.Offset(i-1, 4).Value = fRng.Offset(, 6).Value 'value 6-column further given back to E-column X-sheet
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:
[image]

Rows that are left untouched in the sheet "Second" were not searched for. Hope this clears it up a bit on how to loop the way you explained in the comments.

Comment: The array angle is something I am unfamiliar with, studying your code, i am sure I'll have a question

Comment: I think I understand, I've set sheet names per code, i run it and never affects or finds worksheets

Comment: Should name of the workbook be in there before worksheets

Comment: You mention in your code "Copy of HM_GUIDE macro (2).xlsm" and "beer list macro (2).xlsm", you need to specify that as well instead of `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("X")` for you it'd be something like `Set wsX = Workbooks("Copy of HM_GUIDE macro (2)").Worksheets("X")`

Comment: I think i started of not knowing how to as a question,    Find  wsX "start", increment row, copy cell, goto wsY, paste in "B1", find in wsY value in"B1" in range "A1:E100", copy the value 6 cells over, goto wsX paste value 4 cells over from the origninal incremented value,   LOOP?, then increment 1 row, until STOP_4 and exit i have attached manual macro code.

Comment: ok got it added above

Comment: What's the point in pasting anything in the Y-sheet if you're just overwriting it constantly?

Comment: i have two different databases. Same find value on both but one (Y) has additional data that needs to be brought over to (X). .......The code " sub Loop 100"  is a manual  create macro,..........i want turn that into a loop and row incremnt find........iknow the absolute cells will  change to relative  addresses..........I tried to show before and after screen shots........

Comment: That doesn't answer my question...... at all.

Comment: However, my answer is adjusted, START is being searched for first, E-column in X-sheet is being filled and B1 is the only cell getting edited in the Y-sheet.

Comment: i started my code by 'commenting my steps, then started addiing code based on your array stuff and other snipits and turned it into a non-memory set of instructions. ......pulled all nighter...... im not sure if it needs cleaned up........ not worried about speed yet ,  new code above,, your thoughts?

Comment: You have a few flaws with the offset (for example exiting the do before you process the last value to be searched) but other than that, it should manage what you want. The most important part is that you learn from the mistakes and adapt to what you've learned. There's still no reason to copy paste if the only thing you want are values btw. The "weird negative logic" is used because we don't care when it is Nothing, only when it isn't (aka, we care about when something is found, we don't do anything when nothing was found).